# Visual Studio 2010 / TFS set "local" comments?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, comments

I'm working in VS 2010 and am connected to a Team Foundation Server.

In order to edit source files I have to check them out from the server. After I'm done with editing, I have to check them back in (to make changes visible to everyone else) or discard changes.

I am currently in the process of getting acquainted with the architecture and systems, so I'd like to add a lot of personal comments while I play around with everything.

However I'd prefer to not make these comments visible to everyone else. (And I dont want to delete them everytime I commit changes via check-in)

Is there a VS function I did not yet discover or a plugin that allows me to enter comments that dont get commited to the TFS? Maybe something like virtual post-its, just something that lets me attach stupid reminders on certain blocks of code?

(yes I know, proper documentation would make this obsolete but the system is as it is and its huge and I'm not the one to document this all, just want to get used to the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2010/TFS2010 no built in functionality that I know of, for TFS2012 you could possibly use code reviews.

Maybe the Visual studio extension [StickyNotes](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69b3d5fa-5ad6-4064-a943-4dc7b87a4c80) is what you want.

Comment: yes I was looking for something like this, but unfortunately thats only a trial Version   -edit- and it constantly crashes...